# How to select the drillup button using jquery, so I can do an on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am using highcharts, the pie-drilldown one. I created three buttons outside of the div my highchart is in and when a pie slice is clicked it hides the three buttons, but I want the three buttons to reappear when the drill up button is clicked using jquery. If there is a way to do it without jquery I'm open to that idea too.

```
var $button0 = $('#button0');
var $button1 = $('#button1');
var $button2 = $('#button2');
$('tspan[class=highcharts-text-outline]').click(function () { // WORKS
    $button0.hide(); $button1.hide(); $button2.hide();
    .
    . Other code that doesn't matter
    .
});

$('#highcharts-lb5nb7e-2 > svg > g.highcharts-button.highcharts-drillup-button.highcharts-button-normal').click(function (){ // DOESN'T WORK

    $button0.show(); $button1.show(); $button2.show();
    alert("AM I BEING CALLED?!");
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [events](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events) of highcharts for show and hide of buttons

```
 chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events:{
        drilldown:function(){
        var butonsElems=document.getElementsByTagName('button')
        for(var i=0;i<butonsElems.length;i++){
            butonsElems[i].style.display='none'
        }
      },
      drillup:function(){
        var butonsElems=document.getElementsByTagName('button')
        for(var i=0;i<butonsElems.length;i++){
            butonsElems[i].style.display=''
        }
      }
    }
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emLpgnp2/) Demonstration

Comment: :D IT WORKED!!! 
Thank you!!!
I looked at the highcharts documentation but I find it hard to understand, do you have any tips for learning highcharts?

Comment: Try new things and break the codes which exists official documentation example i.e jsfiddle examples. If you face problems SO is always there but still try to post with  mcve  condition.